# Destroy React Native Webview

Tags: webview, android-webview, react-native

I have a React Native application that uses a WebView to display a Highcharts chart.  It was working for a while but out of nowhere it just stopped loading in Android.  The only fix I could find was to disable Chrome and re-enable it. Which makes me believe there is something going on Chrome on my phone that's making it break.  I see in the Android developer docs, the WebView has a destroy() function.

Is there a way I can call this function from my React Native app?

Answer (score 0):

MMM the purpose of the question is unclear.

You don't want to display the webview ?  don't display it , remove it from the render function.

You want to display the webview ?  display it.

You want to have conditional rendering ?  have it, it will destroy the webview or create a new one. There is a lot of posts of how to have conditional renderind in google.

My suggestion would be... update chrome. If it's already updated, go back to previous versions. If you have android 7+ i think you can change the webview provider in the developer options, if you can, change it to android system webview (you will need to manually install it from the play store). Don't use a native solution for personal device problems.

Comment: From what I've seen is that the Chrome WebView is crashing and the only way to get it back is to disable it on my phone and then re-enable it.  It seems like there is some sort of memory issue.  I was thinking that destroying the WebView would clear it out of memory.  So when the user leaves the page, I would destroy it to clear out its memory and not cause any issues.  There is a destroy function on the Java side, so I would think I could do it on the React Native side